# Check if any element in list is empty/'not a number' (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, list, if-statement

I want to use an if-statement that checks if a list contains an empty element. A line that does something like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,[],2]
list2 = [1,2,1,2]

>>>list1 'contains empty element'
True

>>>list2 'contains empty element'
False
```

I'm very concerned with run time.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Is 0 an "empty element"? and `None`? if so , just use `all`

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about all(). But 0 should be a 'non-empty'-element / a number. Do all() return False if all elements are 0? The list will never contain None's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
any(e == [] for e in my_list)
```

or:

```
[] in my_list
```

if you want  to use an `if-statement`:

```
def check(my_list):
    for e in my_list:
        if e == []:
            return True
    return False

print(check(list1))
print(check(list2))
```

output:

```
True
False
```

Or you can use the ternary operator:

```
True if [] in my_list else False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
all([not (isinstance(x, list) and not x) for x in list1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this.

```
list1 = [1,2,[],2]
list2 = [1,2,1,2]


if [] in list1:
    print("List 1 contains empty list ? ", ([] in list1))

if [] in list2:
    print("List 2 contains empty list ? ", ([] in list2))
```

Or

```
print("List 1 contains empty list ? ", ([] in list1))
print("List 2 contains empty list ? ", ([] in list2))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want any number and any element that has a boolean value of True, try this:

```
def any_empty(lst):
    return not all(isinstance(x, int) or x for x in lst)

print(any_empty([0, 1, 2, 3, ["Foo"]]))
print(any_empty([ () ]))
print(any_empty([ [] ]))
```

Output:

```
False
True
True
```